# Before filter in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller, before-filter

Is this good idea set before filter like this

```
ActionController::Base.before_filter { TitleHelper::Taitl.reset }
```

I use this because rails cache classes, and i need to reset variable to make my script work correct

Also i don't want call it explicitly in ApplicationController

[Here is my code](https://gist.github.com/2689572)

Comment: We need more info. (Show us the code!) You should re-write your code so the class caching doesn't matter rather than needing to reset the class.

Comment: You said ***call** before filter like this*. But you don't call it this way. You just **set it up**.